# PHP Recommendation Engine - Recommending Whiskies with 12 different taste ratings

Tags: php, mysql, system, recommendation-engine

I'm developing a whisky information system in PHP connected to a mySQL database with 3 tables consisting of bottles (about 100 in total), users and bottles certain users have added as a favourite to their whisky shelf.

I'm attempting to build a function to recommend whiskies to the user based on the current whiskies they have added on their whisky shelf.

Each whisky has a 'flavour profile' with 12 different flavour features (e.g. if the whisky is nutty, smoky e.t.c) each feature is ranked on a scale from 0 to 4. So I basically have 12 numbers to play with and compare to another 12 numbers.

I've done a fair bit of research on the subject, but can only find simple implementations comparing one rating to another, but I can't think of an efficient way to compare 12 numbers and return some kind of match percentage.

I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions on the best method to compare the whiskies in the database to the whiskies in the users favourites and recommend the closest matches?

Comment: This question is way too general, and doesn't give us any info about your application. There are hundreds of different techniques for accessing and analyzing data on the web. Try doing some research first.

Comment: I think if your website will act as a reference on the subject, you ought to have developed a methodology for how those profiles relate to each other.  Anybody could come up with a formula to make recommendations based on a set of data... but if you're the whiskey expert, shouldn't you have your own formula?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My apologies for being so general :( I'm unsure on what info you are asking for? What I'm asking for is suggestions for comparing multiple ratings of one product to multiple ratings for another product and computing the distance between the two sets of numbers to come up with a k's nearest neighbour/euclidean distance kind of implementation.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to accomplish is, in essence, **Pandora for Whiskey**. You will have to devise an algorithm which will compare different characteristics and provide some sort of weight that will affect the overall outcome. This is not a trivial process and your algorithm will undergo modification *many* times before it works optimally.

```
| CHARACTERISTICS  |  YOUR WHISKEY  | WHISKEY #1  | WHISKEY #2|
---------------------------------------------------------------
|      Smoky       |       x        |             |     x     |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|      Nutty       |                |      x      |     x     |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

In the above example, *YOUR WHISKEY* is one that you like, and *WHISKEY #2* has more of your desired characteristics than *WHISKEY #1*. That is a very simple comparison, and not doesn't factor very much into it.

You need to sit down with your possible data, create an algorithm, and then try it out on people. If it doesn't quite work right, tweak the algorithm some more. It's a continuous process that will eventually work as you want.

This similar post on collaborative filtering and recommendation systems might provide some more useful insight: [What is algorithm behind the recommendation sites like last.fm, grooveshark, pandora?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268104/what-is-algorithm-behind-the-recommendation-sites-like-last-fm-grooveshark-pan)

Comment: Pandora for Whiskey. Nice. "Are you still drinking? We pay for every glass we pour, and nobody likes trying to share with an empty room"

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response :) I like the concept of this "Pandora for Whisky" and it is actually very helpful in my understanding of recommendation engines. The only thing is, I have no idea how I'd begin coding something like that using SQL statements as I've only been using it for a few months. By 'weighting' do you mean selecting variables of higher importance than the others to compare? Thanks again :)

Comment: Yes. As an example of the complexity it should have, let's say **nutty** and **smoky** don't compliment each other well. You would have to ensure that if one is present, that the other is not. Or if the user likes one of them and not the other that it holds less "weight".

Comment: Just want to say thanks for all your help guys. I've got a pretty good working solution now :)

Comment: @MatthewWatson You should give credit to the user by accepting their answer